# Android custom layout attribute "reference attribute" format?

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, android-xml, declare-styleable

I have a custom view (that extends viewgroup) and I have specified some custom attributes defined in *attrs.xml*....

```
<declare-styleable name="datascope">
    <attr name="colcount" format="integer" />
    <attr name="titleheaderrows" format="integer" />
    <attr name="colheaderrows" format="integer" />
    <attr name="rowlayout" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

The integers I can pickup fine, but the last one - `rowlayout` - I want to use to refer to a further layout file that I will inflate on demand.  But I cannot find the right way to express rowlayout attribute in the main layout file.
I have tried:

```
lui:rowlayout="@layout/sensorvaluesdata">
```

but this fails at runtime:

> E/AndroidRuntime(22092): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'res/layout/sensorvaluesdata.xml' as integer

and

```
lui:rowlayout="?layout/sensorvaluesdata"
```

which fails

> E/AndroidRuntime(22341): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '?2130903043' as integer

Which is interesting 'cos it seems to have stuck the resource ID in there, but stuck a `?` on the front as well.

My *R.java* files does have a sensible looking line for `sensorvaluesdata`.

```
public static final class layout {

    public static final int sensorvaluesdata=0x7f030003;

}
```

what is the right way to do this?

(I can hard code the info into the java source and it works fine....

```
View vx = li.inflate(R.layout.sensorvaluesdata, this, false);
```

Comment: Well this is wierd, tried this again just now and it all works OK. I've checked back and it all looks identical, and I had cleaned the project several times while working through this before the original post.

I can only assume that Eclipse had a wobbly moment - thanks eclipse /)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little more background for someone else. In code use something like this

```
LinearLayout ViewContainer=(LinearLayout) (LayoutInflater.from(context)).inflate(
    attributes.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.[styleableName]_[attributeName], 
        R.layout.[defaultValue]), 
    null);
```

In xml attributes under you styleable name...

```
<attr name="layout" format="reference"/>
```